# How can I change nav bar position?

Tags: html, css, position, nav

I've been trying to fix a navbar position but it is not working correctly. I added margin-top to the nav element but this will create big white space when the user scrolling down. I just want to move the navbar position to the bottom of the header and above content. How can I make this work?
I draw the arrow where I want to move the navbar position.

https://songs-of-hope.tumblr.com/

[image]

Comment: please add code

Comment: Use `your-nav { position: … }`  with absolute, fixed or sticky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just remove the below style from `styles.css` line number 500:

```
#header.bgimage.center .primary {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Or you can set  `padding-bottom: 0px;`. This will solve you problem.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! How can I change the nav bar position in the content area as showing the image above?